# Open linked data_a data set

Tags: dataset, notepad++, rdf, linked-data

I downloaded a data set which is supposed to be in RDF format  http://iw.rpi.edu/wiki/Dataset_1329, using Notepad++ I opened it but can't read it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The file, uncompressed, is about 140MB. Notepad++ is probably failing due to the size of the file. The RDF format used in this dataset is [Ntriples](http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/RDFCore/ntriples/), one triple per line with three components (subject, predicate, object), very human readable. Sample data from the file:

```
<http://data-gov.tw.rpi.edu/raw/1329/data-1329-00017.rdf#entry8389> <http://data-gov.tw.rpi.edu/vocab/p/1329/race_other_multi_racial> "0" .
<http://data-gov.tw.rpi.edu/raw/1329/data-1329-00017.rdf#entry8389> <http://data-gov.tw.rpi.edu/vocab/p/1329/race_black_and_white> "0" .
<http://data-gov.tw.rpi.edu/raw/1329/data-1329-00017.rdf#entry8389> <http://data-gov.tw.rpi.edu/vocab/p/1329/national_origin_hispanic> "0" .
<http://data-gov.tw.rpi.edu/raw/1329/data-1329-00017.rdf#entry8389> <http://data-gov.tw.rpi.edu/vocab/p/1329/filed_cases> "1" .
```

If you want to have a look at the data then try to open it with a tool that streams the file rather than loading it all at once, for instance `less` or `head`.

If you want to use the data you might want to look into loading it in a triple store (4store, Virtuoso, Jena TDB, ...) and use [SPARQL](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/) to query it.

Answer (score -1):

Try [Google Refine](http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/) (possibly with RDF extension: http://lab.linkeddata.deri.ie/2010/grefine-rdf-extension/ )